# Run test periodically in Java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

With to following code I'm receiving data trough API website feed.
Whether someone can give me advice please which is the easiest way **to run this code periodically on let say every 2 minutes** (without clicking on run button manually)?

```
package Twister;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class API {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       byte[] bytes = "username:password".getBytes("UTF-8");        
       String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
       URL api = new URL("https://....");
       URLConnection apiConnection = api.openConnection();
       apiConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Basic " +   encoded );
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(apiConnection.getInputStream()));
       String storm;

        while ((storm = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(storm);

        in.close();
    }
}
```